# Can i use that selenium java code to build it in VSTS

Tags: selenium, azure-devops

I have hybrid framework , which is selenium with java in eclipse. Can i use that whole code to build it in VSTS

Comment: Yes you can. Is there anything specific you're running into? You're question is now very broad and hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If the Hosted agent doesn’t meet the requirement(s) (such as Chrome: [Install headless chrome on hosted build servers](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19387174-install-headless-chrome-on-hosted-build-servers)), you can set up the private agent on your local machine and do build and test with this agent.

[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)